# Flash Mobile app: different RAM consumption on device and on profiler

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, ram, bitmapdata

I'm profiling my flash mobile app and I noticed that the RAM consumption is different when the app runs on device or on the Flash Builder profiler (I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 + Apache Flex 4.9.1 + Air 3.6).

On device (Galaxy Tab 2 or iPad) RAM consumption it's at least double.

- Why? It's possible to avoid this strange behavior?
- While my app uses a lot of BitmapData objects how can I reduce the amount of RAM used on device?
- While publishing on Google Play it's possible to target devices with at least 1GB RAM?

It's a lot of questions... I know

Answer (score 0):

the architecture of the CPU in your PC is different then in your smartphone, ergo it handles RAM management differently. Also The Flash Player is a bit different for that reason, meaning the Garbage Collector can run differently. 
You can specify target devices as well as parameters, I don't remember if its in the xml in the project, or on the developer console in play store. 
you can reduce the amount of ram used, if you remove and create objects wise. of course if you need them, they has to be in the ram.